# Retrieving and setting an image from firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've been trying to retrieve and set an image from firebase storage for a few hours now and I just can't seem to get it.

I've tried it using the Bitmap and setImageBitmap(), but my app crashes when I load the activity.

I have also tried using Glide. Also crashes my activity. I have tried using different images thinking that may be the cause and still crashes.

My current code is:

```
mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(photoUrl);

mStorageReference.getDownloadUrl();

Glide.with(this).load(mStorageReference).into(phProfilePhoto);
```

using the dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you include FirebaseUI (`firebase-ui-storage`), you don't need to call `getDownloadUrl` and can pass the `StorageReference` into Glide directly.

```
mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(photoUrl);

Glide.with(this).load(mStorageReference).into(phProfilePhoto);
```

If this crashes your app, edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stack trace that you get in its logcat output.

Comment: I added the listener and it's still crashing my app. It goes into success but crashes on the line Glide.with(this).load(mStorageReference).into(imageView);

Comment: Using the logcat helped thank you! never really used before until now. phProfilePhoto was pointing to an image view in a different activity smh.